# The meaning of $\pi_1(S^1,(1,0))$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I know what $\pi_1(X,\star)$ means. But what does $\pi_1(S^1,(1,0))$ mean? I came across it when wanting to solve the following problem:

“Let $I\in \pi_1(S^1,(1,0))$ be the class of the identity map. Show that $nI$ is the class of the map $f_n:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ given by $f_n(z)=z^n$.” What does this problem want?

Is $(1,0)$ the two element set consisting of $1$ and $0$, or is it an interval? But in both cases it again does not make sense to me as $0$ is not in the circle.

Comment: $(1,0)$ is the couple that has $1$ as its first coordinate, $0$ its second coordinate

Comment: Oh right, I’ve become so absent-minded. Thanks @Max

Comment: It's a bit weird that when defining the maps $f_n$, $S^1$ is treated as a subset of ${\mathbb C}$, but when specifying the base point $(1,0)$ as a subset of ${\mathbb R}^2$. It seems to make more sense, in this context, to write $\pi_1(S^1,1)$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag yes exactly, maybe that’s why I got confused